# Why does IPersistenceContext.GetEntry return null after IPersistenceContext.UnproxyAndReassociate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I've got a disconnected proxy from an NHibernate session, and I'm attempting to see if it's modified in a second session. In the process, I check if the entity is a proxy, and if it is, perform the following calls:

```
 var proxy = entity as INHibernateProxy;
 var obj = persistenceContext.UnproxyAndReassociate(proxy);
 var oldEntry = persistenceContext.GetEntry(obj);
```

I'd expect at this point that the `oldEntry` would not be null, since the proxy and underlying entity have been reassociated with the `persistenceContext`. However, `UnproxyAndReassociate` doesn't populate the `StatefulPersistenceContext.entityEntries` map with the entity.

Why not? Isn't reassociation considered the same as a load?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the implementation of `UnproxyAndReassociate`:

```
public object UnproxyAndReassociate(object maybeProxy)
{
    var proxy = maybeProxy as INHibernateProxy;
    if (proxy != null)
    {
        ILazyInitializer li = proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer;
        ReassociateProxy(li, proxy);
        return li.GetImplementation(); //initialize + unwrap the object 
    }
    return maybeProxy;
}
```

it seems that it reassociates the *proxy* and that you get the unproxied object back. `ReassociateProxy` does:

```
private void ReassociateProxy(ILazyInitializer li, INHibernateProxy proxy)
{
    if (li.Session != Session)
    {
        IEntityPersister persister = session.Factory.GetEntityPersister(li.EntityName);
        EntityKey key = new EntityKey(li.Identifier, persister, session.EntityMode);
        // any earlier proxy takes precedence
        if (!proxiesByKey.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            proxiesByKey[key] = proxy;
        }
        proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer.Session = Session;
    }
}
```

So it is stored in the dictionary `proxiesByKey`.

```
public EntityEntry GetEntry(object entity)
{
    return (EntityEntry)entityEntries[entity];
}
```

`GetEntry` doesn't even consider the proxiesByKey, so reassociating a proxy is not the same as reassociating the underlying entry with a session.